# App Catalog Deployment Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, sharepoint-addin

I just uploaded an app package file (.sppkg) to my App Catalog that I just created in our Office365 environment.  The package uploaded, but the deployment failed.  My question is: Is there any kind of error log that I can view that will give more details on why it failed?  The only message that I see under the "App Package Error Message" is:

"Deployment failed.  Correlation ID: 7dc37b9e-b07f-6000-0c42-d42b5eceadc3"

I feel like I should be able to use this Correlation ID to find a log entry, but I'm not sure where to look. Any suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: Is seems that you need to raise a service request with MS now. Refer to this : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99493c01-593f-4b73-96f1-a80f3c037909/how-to-view-details-of-correlation-id-on-a-sharepoint-online-site?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

Comment: Looks most likely to be an issue with you solution. Please run the gulp commands and check if there are any errors ? If there are errors, then the deployment will fail

Comment: Wow, looks like you are right about the service request @VipulKelkar. Thats nuts.  Do you want to write that into an answer, and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you need to raise a service request with MS now. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/99493c01-593f-4b73-96f1-a80f3c037909/how-to-view-details-of-correlation-id-on-a-sharepoint-online-site?forum=onlineservicessharepoint

Answer (score 0):

It is a known error if you created your App Catalog recently, you should wait for 20-40 minutes and redeploy your package, it should work. if did not check your codes for error
run

```
 gulp serve
```

and see if there is any error on the console

hope this help someone who face same issue